# database query "like" with multiple "%"

Tags: mysql, database, sql-like

I tried to select filtered data from the database to serialize. I want to ignore the `s:` value from this query so I use `%`, but it always shows the wrong query. What's the right query for this example?

```
return Temp::where(function($q) use ($name, $key, $value) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++) {
      $q->where('keys','like','%"'.$key[$i].'";s:%:"'.$value[$i].'";%');
   }
})->first();
```

[image: query example]

Comment: you should escape quotes and % symbol

Comment: @jophab `select \`keys\` from \`temp\` where \`keys\` LIKE '\%"item_id";s:\%:"17";\%'` return empty value

Comment: dont escape first and last %. I'm not sure about the way of escaoing

Comment: only escaping `s:\%` but still not working